# Deploying dacpac: How to remove system versioning from table?

Tags: sql-server, deployment, dacpac, temporal-tables

We have a Visual Studio solution with database projects which we deploy through Devops. When we remove system versioning from a table, by **altering the definition of the table and removing the history table in the project**, we get an error in the deployment of the dacpac:

> Drop table operation failed on table '[schema].[ourTableHistory]' because it is not a supported operation on system-versioned temporal tables.

Looks like the dacpac does not see the dependency from the history table on the 'parent' system-versioned table.
We also tried using a pre-deployment script to disable the system versioning from the table, but then the generated scripts from the dacpac are out of sync with the target database and we get other errors...

Comment: It is probably not a good idea to have the history table definition in our database project, although a schema-compare from db to project will create one